# Increment nested field value in mongodb if exists or create nested fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, increment, subdocument

I need to increment the multi level nested field value if it exists or create the complete nested field Object structure.

Structure of my document

```
Doc1 {
_id:ObjectId(),
myField: {
  nested:{
      x: 5,
      y: 10,
      z: 20
  }
 }
}
```

**Goal Explanation**: I need a way to write a single query:

- **If myField exists**: Increment the value of my nested field
  **myField.nested.x** by 10.
- **If myField does not exists**:  Create the below field with initial values same as given in the **Doc1**.

**Attempt and explanation**:

```
 db.collection('collectionName').findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id:"userId","myField" : { $exists : true }},
    {$inc:{'myField.nested.x':10}
 })
```

This way, I can  increment the nested field if it exists but in case of non existence I cannot set *myField* as same as Doc1.

Although, I can use another query after response in my NodeJs callback to achieve my required behaviour. But I need some elegant solution in  a single query.

I am using MongoDB version 4.0.4, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If the field does not exist, $inc creates the field and sets the field to the specified value.    db.collection('collectionName').findOneAndUpdate({_id:"userId"},
    {$inc:{'myField.nested.x':10}
 })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this query**

If the field does not exist, $inc creates the field and sets the field to the specified value.

```
db.collection('collectionName').findOneAndUpdate({_id:"userId"},
{$inc:{'myField.nested.x':10}
})
```

Comment: How does this work with dates? If I want to add 6 months to a date, but if the date doesn't exist, choose $$NOW as the date?